# Status Code repeated throughout the JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a JSP which contains more than 2500 LoC.

Most of the code contribution in that page is by Javascript& jQuery.

```
 error: function(res) {
                ajaxFailed(res);
            },
            statusCode: {
                400: function()
                {
                    alert("Bad Request.");
                },
                403: function()
                {
                    alert("You are not logged in, or your session timed out. Please login and try again.");
                    window.parent.location.reload(true);
                },
                404: function()
                {
                    alert("Not Found.");
                }
            }
```

Above code snippet is used > 20 occurences.

Is there any way that I can make it as a common method and invoke in all places.

P.S. So that I can save 300 lines of code

Comment: Well, if this is an object, then just make a variable, set it to that object, and then just pass in that variable.

Comment: Problem #1: a JSP with 2.5kloc. In any case, make an external function and refer to it in the `error` attribute, or use the normal jQuery ajaxError functionality.

Comment: Yeah. that is the key area i'm working on right now. Helping the team improvise the code. Reduce lines of code by extracting code and creating generalized methods

Comment: @DaveNewton As you noticed in the code snippet, already using a function named ajaxFailed() for error scenario. I wanted a same kind of snippet for statuscode too

Comment: ... Did you see the answer? That aside, the name of *your* `ajaxFailed` function is irrelevent; that it happens to be named the same as a jQuery method used to register a general-purpose Ajax error handler is not important. You're passing an anonymous function as the `error` parameter. Make it not be an anonymous function, and use the reference to that function as the `error` value. You might want to take a step back and run through some JS basics before going too much further, because this is pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global `ajaxError()` method which would only need to be included once in a page.

**[ajaxError() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)**

Alternatively create an error handler function and pass it as reference to each of your existing calls:

```
function myErrorHandler(res) {
                ajaxFailed(res);
            },
            statusCode: {.........}
}


$.ajax({

  url:'...',
   data: data,
   success: function(){},
  error: myErrorHandler
})
```